# Spotify-app style slide up UX

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to implement an iOS view where it's similar to Spotify's view. If you've used Spotify, you'll notice as the list of songs slide up, it covers the entire screen, but the Shuffle Play button stays at the top. How do they implement it? Here are my thoughts, not sure if that's right...

[image]

[image]
[image]

Comment: To answer this, it would require a LOT of code, but I can try leading you in the right direction. Look into presentation transitions for modal view controllers. You can take a view from the presenting VC, move it to the correct location during the transition, then when the transition ends, it looks like the same button, but is actually a different instance. It can be a little tricky to wrap your head around, though.

Comment: @Dean were you able to find a framework to do this?

Comment: If you use UICollectionView, this is great: https://github.com/jamztang/CSStickyHeaderFlowLayout